# How do I combine that

Tags: regex, merge

I have these texts:

```
1000
2000
3000
4000
5000
6000
```

Now I want them to be like that but each one in a single line not all in one line, like in the picture:

```
1000:2000
3000:4000
5000:6000
```

Comment: let us know what you have tried

Comment: PS: I want to use Reagular Expression on Notepad++

Answer (score 0):

You can use following regex (tested on VSCode)

```
^(.*)\n(.*)$
```

and replacement text as

```
$1:$2
```

Comment: I tried it on Notepad++ but did not work, I need a method that could be useful using Regular Expression on Notepad++ please?

Comment: I tried it on Notepad++ but did not work, I need a method that could be helpful using Regular expression on Notepad++ please?

Comment: @Thatsit Try matching the digits and use `\R` to match the newlines `^(\d+)\R(\d+)$` and replace with `$1:$2`

Comment: @The fourth bird what if there is mix of digits and letters?

Comment: @Thatsit Then you can use `(.*)` to match 0+ times any char including whitespace chars, or `(.+)` to match 1+ times. If you don't want to match spaces, `(\S+)` to match non whitespace chars or `(\w+)` to match only word characters.

Comment: Thanks I got it, but what if I want to make the right value (after the colon dots) looks like the left one.
For example:

ABC
DEF

into this:

ABC:ABC
DEF:DEF